# Is there a mistake in the GCM Quick Start?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, google-cloud-messaging

It is my first time using the Google Cloud Messaging. And I am trying to understand [this guide](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/gcm/app/src/main/java/gcm/play/android/samples/com/gcmquickstart/MainActivity.java).

In the `onCreate` method, a `BroadcastReceiver` is defined. It is necessary to update the UI when the registration token is received.

In the same method (line 67) there is a condition. This "if" checks if the Google Play Service is available on the device, and finally, the [RegistrationIntentService](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/gcm/app/src/main/java/gcm/play/android/samples/com/gcmquickstart/RegistrationIntentService.java) is called.

I think that getToken method (line 53) is not async, and that is the reason to use a `Intent Service` (I understand a service comparing it with a thread).

My doubt is about the comment (line 46). It says "subsequent calls are local". But I never saw a reading of `SharedPreferences` in the MainActivity. So, the `Intent Service` is always started, right?

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: the reading is in the broadcast receiver. and yes, the service is started every time the activity is started. but since the subsequent `getToken` is effectively local, this is very fast

Comment: if I want to associate the registration token with an account in my database, I should save the registration token in a global variable (for use later) or is better to use the `BroadcastReceiver` in my RegisterActivity?